# Describe level surfaces of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am doing an exam review that has no answer key and am not sure how to approach this question.

[image]

Since there are three variables on the right side of the equation, is this to be treated as a 4-dimensional equation?  I know x^2 + y^2 is a 3D bowl, but not sure how the graph changes including -E^Z.

By "sketch gradient field vectors", does that mean just zoom-in on parts of what the contour diagram would look like and draw a gradient vector at a point?

Answer (score 1):

No,this is not treated **in this case** as a four dimensional equation-it is a series of level surfaces in $R^3$ of a function of 4 variables where w= 0 where w $\in R^{4}$ 
$z=x^2+y^2$ is this function's two dimensional counterpart,so you're perfectly right to look at it for inspiration. As that function has 3 different level curves depending on the value of z= c, f(x,y,z) has 3 different level surfaces in $R^3$ depending on which variable is taken as the constant. We proceed as follows:

[image]

As for sketching the gradient vectors, yes,that's more or less what it means. For example, take x =1 and y=1 for the gradient vector $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$={2x,2y,0} = (2,2,0). Remember, $E^2$ is a constant value in z. So this yields the gradient at the point. You should be able to take it from here.